# lucene sort friend search result by recent contact activity

Tags: search, lucene, indexing

I use Lucene to index user list in my application.

How can I sort the user search result by recent activity
Example:
Anna has just sent an email to Peter.
So when Anna Search with character "P"
Peter must be have high rank than Pill or Peo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to constantly update the index with the recent activity (which unfortunately involves dropping & adding documents -- Lucene does not have an "update" action for documents).

Comment: Well, IndexWriter.updateDocument does exist, though it IS essentially just a wrapper for a delete-and-add.